# How to filter products by rating in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, filter, ratings

I want to get all products by rating filter.
here my code

```
$getProducts = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$getProducts->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$getProducts->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
```

So, how can I add here filter for rating so I need not to first get all product and then check all product with that rating issue.

thanks

Comment: This will help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102722/magento-2-rating-filter-in-layered-navigation

Comment: @MichaelHa thanks I will try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the below code for filter product collection by rating percent:

```
$collection = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('rova'=> 'rating_option_vote_aggregated'),'e.entity_id =rova.entity_pk_value', array("percent" => 'percent'))->group('e.entity_id');

$collection->getSelect()->where("rova.percent = 80");

foreach($collection as $product){
    //YOUR CODE
}
```

100 Percent = 5 Star Rating

90 Percent = 4.5 Star Rating

80 Percent = 4 Star Rating

and so on...

Comment: can you give me average counting percentage?

Comment: You need to customise the query for that.

Comment: Yes but for average how can I write query can you tell me sir.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override model from core like below.

then you have to extends in your local custom file.
class ProductRepository extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository

Then you have to right below getlist function for custom rating code collection.

public function getList(SearchCriteriaInterface $searchCriteria)
{

```
    $searchCriteriaData = $this->http->get('searchCriteria');
    

    if (!$searchCriteria) {
        return;
    }
    foreach (array_keys((array)$searchCriteriaData) as $key) {
        $value = &$searchCriteriaData[$key];
        unset($searchCriteriaData[$key]);
        $searchCriteriaData[SimpleDataObjectConverter::camelCaseToSnakeCase($key)] = $value;
    }

    

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($collection);

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $this->joinPositionField($collection, $searchCriteria);


    if(isset($searchCriteriaData['filter_groups'][1]['filters'][0]['field']) && $searchCriteriaData['filter_groups'][1]['filters'][0]['field'] == 'rat')
    {
        
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('rova'=> 'rating_option_vote_aggregated'),'e.entity_id =rova.entity_pk_value',array("percent as rating"))
        ->where("rova.percent between ".$searchCriteriaData['filter_groups'][1]['filters'][0]['value']." and ".$searchCriteriaData['filter_groups'][1]['filters'][1]['value'])
        ->group('e.entity_id') ->GROUP("rova.percent");            
        $count = $collection->count();
         
    }else{
        $this->collectionProcessor->process($searchCriteria, $collection);      
    }
    

    $collection->load();

    $collection->addCategoryIds();
    $this->addExtensionAttributes($collection);
    $searchResult = $this->searchResultsFactory->create();
    $searchResult->setSearchCriteria($searchCriteria);
    $searchResult->setItems($collection->getItems());
    if(isset($searchCriteriaData['filter_groups'][1]['filters'][0]['field'] ) && $searchCriteriaData['filter_groups'][1]['filters'][0]['field'] == 'rat')
    {
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($count);    
    }else{
        $searchResult->setTotalCount($collection->getSize());    
    }
    

    foreach ($collection->getItems() as $product) {
        $this->cacheProduct(
            $this->getCacheKey(
                [
                    false,
                    $product->getStoreId()
                ]
            ),
            $product
        );
    }

    return $searchResult;
}
```

This is for rest API.