# Magento 2.3.3 - Rating filter in Layer navigation

Tags: magento2.3

I have tried below solution given by Pradeep Kumar which has 7 upvoted but the filter is not appearing in Layer navigation.

Link: [Magento 2 : Rating Filter in Layered Navigation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102722/magento-2-rating-filter-in-layered-navigation)

I have already cross-checked all the files. Someone guide me How to add rating filter in layer navigation Magento 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

For Rating filter in Layer navigation use below module

https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation-for-magento-2.html

https://mirasvit.com/magento-2-extensions/layered-navigation.html

Comment: if you want to give any suggestion then you can give in add a comment option instead of an answer. Bro, I don't want to purchase any plugin. I need to understand the filter rating code by any free custom module.  Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try our layered navigation
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-layered-navigation-extension/