# Magento 2.3.4 how to Develop custom filter in left layered navigation?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am developing a custom module to add the custom filter in left layered navigation,currently we have custom product collection and want to add the filter in layered navigation with three option:

```
1.All Product
2.Available Item
3.Sold Items
```

On forum I got some useful link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103453/24878

and tried to add same as the described in this link but it seems this link is old and not working in current Magento version 2.3.4 .

If anyone work like this type of work please share me so I can implement in my code also.

Please share you ideas.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Can you use standard product attributes and then use standard filter capability?

If you have a yes/no select attributes on the products 'available_filter', 'sold_filter' then make these attributes to be filterable in the layered navigation.

Then set the attribute values as yes / no and the products will filter correctly without any additional code being required.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion .product collection is totally different, if I apply your solution then that's good for default collection but in my case it will not work.